# Android - Ciclo para verificar se uma CheckBox está ativada ou não

Tags: android

Dentro do evento de um `Button` tenho um ciclo `while` que está constantemente a verificar o estado de uma `CheckBox`. O problema é que se a `CheckBox` for ativada a Atividade congela!
Alguém me pode ajudar na solução deste problema?

```
botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        while(checkbox1.isSelected()){

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CheckBox está ativada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CheckBox já não está ativada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: Congela durante quanto tempo?

Comment: Não entendi o porquê daquele *sleep*.

Comment: Congela porque a execução não sai do `while`. Se explicar qual é o objectivo que quer conseguir com esse código, talvez se encontre uma forma alternativa.

Comment: O objetivo do `while` é só verificar se a `checkbox` está ativa?

Comment: Me parece que aquele `while` poderia ser substituído por um `if`.

Comment: A ideia, é de tempo a tempo ser executado um código que vai alterar a mensagem de uma TextView, mas só no caso da Checkbox estar ativa (razão do sleep dentro do While).

Comment: Você deve usar um `AsyncTask` para fazer isso. Vou preparar uma resposta.

Comment: ramaral, desde já obrigado pela sua ajuda. Fico aguardar a sua resposta...

Comment: @ramaral, talvez um `TimerTask` junto com um `Timer` seja uma melhor solução que uma `AsyncTask`, pela natureza do problema, não tenho certeza. Isso também porque o `Timer` roda em uma Thread separada da `MainThread`.

Comment: Podia mostrar-me um exemplo? Obrigado.

Comment: @Wakim Sim tem razão. Dê você a resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seguindo a sugestão do Wakim o código seria este:

```
public class TesteActivity extends Activity {

    Timer timer;
    TimerTask timerTask;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    CheckBox checkBox1;
    TextView textView1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.teste);

        textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        checkBox1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        checkBox1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){//Se está checado inicializa o TimerTask

                    startTimer();
                }
                else{//se não pára o TimerTask
                    stopTimerTask();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void startTimer() {

        timer = new Timer();

        //Inicializa o TimerTask
        initializeTimerTask();

        //Executa imediatamente o TimerTask, repetindo-o a cada 1s
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000); //
    }

    int i = 0;
    public void initializeTimerTask() {

        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {


                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        //Coloque aqui o código que quer que seja executado quando
                        //o CheckBox está checked
                        //Neste exemplo o valor do textView será incementado em 1 a cada segundo
                        i++;
                        textView1.setText(Integer.toString(i));
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }

    public void stopTimerTask() {
        //Pára o timer
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Quando o `CheckBox` é checado o `TimerTask`  é iniciado. Quando o *ckeck* é retirado o `TimerTask` é parado.

Se o `TimerTask` não necessitar de estar rodando quando a *Activity* estiver em segundo plano, faça o *override* dos métodos `onPause` e `onResume` desta forma:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    stopTimerTask();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(checkBox1.isChecked()){
        startTimer();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wakim e ramaral, obrigados pelos dois exemplos. Eu hoje não vou poder testar, mas amanhã deixo aqui uma resposta. Obrigados.

Comment: Wakim e ramaral, a vossa ajuda funciona perfeitamente. Obrigado aos dois.

Answer (score 2):

Minha sugestão é bem simples, usar um `Timer` para executar uma tarefa de verificação em determinados períodos:

```
private static final long INTERVAL = 4000l;

Timer mTimer;
Button mButton;
Checkbox mCheckbox;

TimerTask mVerifyTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        verificarCheckbox();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Realizar sua inicializacao

    mTimer = new Timer();

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mTimer.cancel();
            mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mVerifyTask, INTERVAL);
        }
    });

void verificarCheckbox() {
    if(mCheckbox.isChecked()) {
        if(Looper.myLooper() != Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { notificarNaMainThread });
        } else {
            notificarNaMainThread();
        }
    }
}

void notificarNaMainThread() {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CheckBox está ativada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Uma observação**: Não é permitido alterações de `View's` fora da `MainThread`, mas consultas ao estado é permitido. Se não houver aproveitamento do método `verificarCheckbox` para ser usado no `Timer´ e fora dele, então o

```
if(Looper.myLooper() != Looper.getMainLooper()) {
```

não é necessário, podendo ser simplificado.

Comment: Como você não respondia, estive a preparar uma resposta. Se não levar mal irei postá-la.

Comment: É que estava a caminho do trabalho, mas pode postar sem problema nenhum, posso até apagar a minha hehe.

Comment: Ficam as duas .

Comment: (+1) O OP escolheu a minha resposta, no entanto a sugestão foi sua.